# mod_rewrite remapping not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to get a .htaccess File to work, that remaps some URLs for my Webservices. I've got the following Code in my .htaccess File:

```
 # General Settings
 Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
 Allow from all
 AddCharset utf-8 .css .html .php

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 # Option 1: Remove Index.php from URL
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 # Custom Options: Webservices
 RewriteRule ^applications/([0-9]+)/infobox\.xml$ app/makeInfoBox/$1/ [L]
```

Removing index.php works just fine, so I assume mod_rewrite is working properly. But why does my Webservice rule not work?

It should remap https://example.com/applications/258/infobox.xml to https://example.com/app/makeInfoBox/258/ or shouldn't it?

When I add the [R] Flag it does work, but I don't want to URL redirected, I want it remapped.

Thanks for your answers!

Edit:
So after some Testing I reached the point where I'm really out of ideas. This is my mod_rewrite Code:

```
 # General Settings
 AddCharset utf-8 .css .html .php

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 # Custom Options: Webservices
 RewriteRule ^applications/([0-9]+)/infobox\.xml$ app/makeInfoBox/$1/ [DPI]

 # Option Remove Index.php from URL
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I now have logging activated with a high log-level. Here is what is logged:

add path info postfix: /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/applications -> /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/applications/258/infobox.xml

strip per-dir prefix: /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/applications/258/infobox.xml -> applications/258/infobox.xml

applying pattern '^applications/([0-9]+)/infobox\.xml$' to uri 'applications/258/infobox.xml'

rewrite 'applications/258/infobox.xml' -> 'app/makeInfoBox/258/'

add per-dir prefix: app/makeInfoBox/258/ -> /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/app/makeInfoBox/258/

strip per-dir prefix: /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/app/makeInfoBox/258/ -> app/makeInfoBox/258/

applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'app/makeInfoBox/258/'

RewriteCond: input='/etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/app/makeInfoBox/258/' pattern='!-f' => matched

RewriteCond: input='/etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/app/makeInfoBox/258/' pattern='!-d' => matched

rewrite 'app/makeInfoBox/258/' -> '/index.php?/app/makeInfoBox/258/'

split uri=/index.php?/app/makeInfoBox/258/ -> uri=/index.php, args=/app/makeInfoBox/258/

trying to replace prefix /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/ with /

trying to replace context docroot /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices with context prefix

internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

strip per-dir prefix: /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/index.php -> index.php

applying pattern '^applications/([0-9]+)/infobox\.xml$' to uri 'index.php'

strip per-dir prefix: /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/index.php -> index.php

applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'

RewriteCond: input='/etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched

pass through /etc/apache2/htdocs/webservices/index.php

Comparing the log output when redirecting and when remapping shows that it's nearly exact the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^applications/([\d]+)/infobox.xml$ app/makeInfoBox/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: I tied it out, but isn't it the wrong way around?
I want that when I access  https://example.com/applications/258/infobox.xml mod_rewrite maps it locally to https://example.com/app/makeInfoBox/258/ but doesn't change the URL.

I got CodeIgniter in on my Server, and the URl is the path to one of my Functions (controller(app)->methode(makeInfoBox)->Parameter(id=258))

Comment: what url you are entering in to browser and what is the original url please mention separately?

Comment: I enter https://example.com/applications/258/infobox.xml and my apache should map it to my CodeIgniter function, which puts out data of one of our applications (the one with id=258) saved in the company's CMDB in XML form (so https://example.com/app/makeInfoBox/258/). So the xml File Infobox.xml I try to access does not exist exactly, it is just the ouput of the function.

Comment: I think this is some internal problem I have to figure out.. The code should work but it still remains unchanged. Maybe I have to change some Apache settings? because Redircts work, but mapping seems not to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well without using rewriting it is working but only after rewriting it has no response so i suggest you to tweak the rule for testing with some relatively same url and then observe the result and apply back to your current rule.

Comment: Edited the original Post with some more information.